# Why can't R draw density plot?

Tags: r, density-plot

I have run a bivariate threshold excess modell and want to plot the diagnostic plots. I get this error message.

```
Error in contour.default(xvec, yvec, dens, main = main, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab,  : 
invalid NA contour values
```

Code

```
m1 <- fbvpot(matr1, thresh, model = "log")
plot(m1)
```

does not give any result for the density plot

Here are the model results

```
Call: fbvpot(x = matr1, threshold = thresh, model = "log") 
Likelihood: censored 
Deviance: 4949.319 
AIC: 4959.319 
Dependence: 0.0009124526 

Threshold: -3.5023 15.7616 
Marginal Number Above: 440 440 
Marginal Proportion Above: 0.5577 0.5577 
Number Above: 258 
Proportion Above: 0.327 

Estimates
 scale1   shape1   scale2   shape2      dep  
 1.6107  -0.4623   3.9580  -0.2119   0.9993  

Standard Errors
   scale1     shape1     scale2     shape2        dep  
7.749e-02  2.291e-02  2.165e-01  2.894e-02  2.002e-06  

Optimization Information
  Convergence: successful 
  Function Evaluations: 91 
  Gradient Evaluations: 10
```